# How to create REST API in noir to receive list of ids?

Tags: rest, clojure, noir

How I can have an API which can be called as `http://our.api.com/product/<id1>,<id2>` and receive the list of ids using webnoir ?

Comment: Don't use comma separated values in URL. Instead use query string to pass the product ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defpage product-view "/product/:ids" {:keys [ids]}
  (str (into [] (map #(Integer/parseInt %) (.split ids "-"))))
  )
```

here one parameter (ids) is passed to split by "-", and then each element is parsed as int
for url 
  http://our.api.com/product/11-222-3
the output will be 
  [11 222 3]

you can select other separator then "-", but ,.; are not working (i have no time to figure what it is: restriction of ring or smth else)

Comment: This is just missing a set of square brackets:
`(defpage [:get ["/product/:ids"]] {:keys [ids]}
  (json (map #(Integer/parseInt %) (.split ids ","))))`

You could also add a regex:

`(defpage [:get ["/product/:ids" :ids #"\d+(,\d+)*"]] {:keys [ids]}
  (json (map #(Integer/parseInt %) (.split ids ","))))`

Comment: @mikebridge, I'm recieving CompilerException java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE068 class name is invalid; class=...$GET_LBRACK__DOUBLEQUOTE___product___GT_ids_DOUBLEQUOTE_ _GT_ids _SHARP__DOUBLEQUOTE__BSLASH_d_PLUS_(,_BSLASH_d_PLUS_)_LT__DOUBLEQUOTE__RBRACK_$fn__4617

Comment: strange---what combination of clojure/java are you running?

Comment: I ran into the same CompilerException today when I didn't have the regex inside the vector with the route definition.

Comment: [org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
   [noir "1.3.0-beta1"]